# What is wrong with this imperative version of factorial function in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

```
let impfac i = 
  let l = ref i in
  let result = ref 1 in
  let k = ref 2 in
  while !k < !l do
    result := !result * !k
      k:=!k+1
  done;
  !result
```

The error message is:

```
let impfac i = 
  let l = ref i in
  let result = ref 1 in
  let k = ref 2 in
  while !k < !l do
    result := !result * !k
      k:=!k+1
  done;
  !result;;
                Characters 121-123:
      result := !result * !k
                          ^^
Error: This expression is not a function; it cannot be applied
#
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
result := !result * !k
  k:=!k+1
```

You're missing a semicolon at the end of the first line. Because of this it is read as:

```
result := !result * (!k k:=!k+1)
```

i.e. it thinks you're trying to call `!k` with `k:=!k+1` as its argument.

This is also why your editor indented the line with `k := !k+1` farther to the right than the line above it. That should have been the first sign that something's wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Perfect!!! Problem solved!!! Thanks for your help!!! I love the indenting hint!!!